# The android SDK requires ADT version 23.0.0 or above

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been working on a project and unfortunately updated android SDK tools and installed Google API in Eclipse. Now it comes up with an error **The android SDK requires ADT version 23.0.0 or above** (However I have installed ADT bundle just 2 days ago and unable to find the updated version when I check for *Install new Software* in *Windows* menu) and my project is not compiling as well with errors **build path is incomplete** , **unable to resolve target android-10. As before it was all working fine.** 
I have also tried various ways to fix by deleting the libraries from **Java Build Path** and restarted the project and shifting the work space nothing works for me. A bit frustrated.

Comment: i have installed it before and it was working fine before updates

Comment: maybe you have to update your ADT again

Comment: @GaurawYadav You can't somehow update because whenever you search for a new update for ADT Eclipse will show you a message saying that **No updates were found**.

Comment: If you don't want to use the new versions, but rather whatever last one fully worked with Eclipse, you can with some searching find the (official) download path of an older distribution, even though it's not longer visible on the website.  You might also see if you still have a working version in your downloads folder or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue sometime back.The best solution to this is to download the ADT again from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html however i would recommend switching to **Android Studio**.

There are a few other ways to restore the same but the it's not worth the time you'll have to invest into that.

Comment: wish had not installed it :/

Comment: I agree, deleting the whole SDK and installing a new one is a painful job